# Androidで同一アイテムに対して課金テストを複数回行う方法

Tags: android, アプリ内課金

Androidの課金テストを行うため、テスト用のアカウントを作成しました。
一度しか購入できないアイテムのため、
このアカウントでテスト課金を行うと二度と同じアイテムを課金テストできなくなります。

同じアカウントで、同じアイテムに対して複数回課金テストをするにはどうすればいいのでしょうか。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

方法は2つあります。

- ペイメント Merchant Centerでテスト課金に対し取り消しを行う
- アプリ側にデバッグ用としてConsumeを実装する

Answer (score 3):

Androidのアイテム課金には「消費」という概念があります。これによって、買い切りアイテムでも一人で複数回買えるようになっています。

参考
[アイテム課金についての参考記事](http://y-anz-m.blogspot.jp/2013/02/android-api-version3.html)

こちらの「・購入アイテムの消費」の項目が参考になるかと思います。